# Enabling Push Notification Xamarin.Android runtime BB 10 App

Tags: push-notification, xamarin.android, blackberry-10

I am following [this](https://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/creating_push-enabled_android_apps.html) doc to enable push in **Xamarin.Android runtime BB10** app. I am confused where & when exactly to put android.cfg file.

- Before creating apk, added cfg file in root of project in application
  name (tried naming as android.cfg also).
- Using that apk, I generated .bar file, but under android folder, res
  folder and apk file only exist, cfg file doesn't seems to be exist.
- Then I tried adding cfg file under bar file after creating apk but
  before signing bar file, but I started getting following error:

> Error: No manifest. Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
>   java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
>   sorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at net.rim.tools.signing.SigningMain.main(SigningMain.java:72) Caused by: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: No
>   manifest.
>           at net.rim.device.codesigning.barsigner.BarSigner.if(Unknown Source)
>           at net.rim.device.codesigning.barsigner.BarSigner.main(Unknown Source)
>           ... 5 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No manifest.
>           at net.rim.device.codesigning.barsigner.BarSigner.try(Unknown Source)
>           ... 7 more

I have ppgurl, appid which I got from BB.

What is the exact procedure for this? In same doc following thing is given:

> The Google Play Services SDK is not supported on BlackBerry 10. If
>   your app includes GCM services, you must set up your Android project
>   to use the stand-alone GCM SDK. Android Studio does not support the
>   use of the stand-alone GCM SDK at this time. For more information see
>   Android Studio Overview.

I am using [GCM Client](https://components.xamarin.com/view/gcmclient/) component for push in Xamarin.Android. What is stand alone GCM SDK given in doc?. I don't know what kind of GCM I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed above issue and now I am receiving push notification successfully in my BlackBerry device. In different places different location is given to place android.cfg file, but actual location which worked for me is:

> android.cfg file under assets/blackberry/android.cfg

Place this file before creating apk. Because in many places I read to put this file after creating apk using zip tool, that may also work, but if it is not working try the solution given here :)

I followed procedures exactly given in below docs.

https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-Android-Runtime-Samples/tree/master/SamplePushClient